# Cambiar motor en la base de datos

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, mysql-workbench

Buenas estoy realizando una API , tengo las clases *Persona*, *Requisitoria* y *Deuda*; estoy utilzando [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate), [spring-boot](/questions/tagged/spring-boot).

Lo que intento hacer es que me cree la BD desde el código ,lo cual lo hace pero el problema va cuando me crea las relaciones. Las relaciones son las siguientes:

1. *Persona* tiene muchas *Deudas*.
2. *Persona* tiene muchas *Requisitorias*.

La clase *Persona* es:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persona")
public class Persona implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 8, max = 8)
    private int dni;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = com.example.model.Deuda.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "persona")
    private List<Deuda> deuda;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = com.example.model.Requisitoria.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "persona")
    private List<Requisitoria> requisitoria;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
}
```

La clase *Deuda* es:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "deuda")
public class Deuda implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    private double deuda;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=com.example.model.Persona.class,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotNull
    private Persona persona;
    public Deuda() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Me crea normal las tablas, pero cuando quiero ver el diagrama de la BD, no me esta relacionando las tablas:

Lo que esta marcado con rojo es la posible respuesta, me dice que tengo que cambiar el motor de BD por que en spring boot esta usado *MyIsam* y lo que me dice el mensaje es usar *InnoDB*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta sería como lo soluciono, o como modificar para que spring boot utilice *InnoDB*

application.properties de spring:

```
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reniec
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

Comment: Puedes poner los valores que tengas en el application.properties?

Comment: ya modifico mi pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a poner el motor

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
```

---

para poder cambiar de motor se agrega `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect` al archivo de propiedades.

Comment: ahora no me crea ni las tablas

Comment: Qué versión de MySQL tienes?

Comment: ya esta arreglado solo es remplazando spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

Comment: Si, era lo que me había faltado. Si te ha servido la respuesta considera marcarla como solución